# Interpretation of mixed-effects model

Tags: r

I used `lme4` in R to fit the mixed model

```
mixedmodel<-lmer((FMI)~MVPAper + Age + (1|Child_ID))
```

Where `FMI` and `MVPAper` are continuous, `Age` is a factor with four levels, and the `Child_ID` is from 1 to 1029 for each participant. I get the following output:

```
> summary(mixedmodel)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: (FMI) ~ MVPAper + Age + (1 | Child_ID)

REML criterion at convergence: 34444.6

Scaled residuals: 
 Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-1.216 -0.123 -0.093  0.061 51.872 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Child_ID (Intercept)   6.459   2.541  
Residual             283.758  16.845  
Number of obs: 4048, groups:  Child_ID, 1023

Fixed effects:
          Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  2.1850969  0.5697864   3.835
MVPAper      0.0028865  0.0007984   3.615
Age9         0.0908241  0.7482005   0.121
Age12       -0.3519625  0.7478261  -0.471
Age15       -0.4881878  0.7499429  -0.651

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) MVPApr Age9   Age12 
MVPAper -0.350                     
Age9    -0.639 -0.040              
Age12   -0.652 -0.004  0.498       
Age15   -0.671  0.056  0.494  0.496
```

I am having troubles interpreting this data. My main aim is to observe whether there is a trend of my response in relation to age and the MVPA.

Comment: Run anova(mixedmodel).  This will give significance tests for each variable.  Then you can interpret the fixed effects in a similar way to how you would interpret them for a standard linear model.

Comment: > anova(mixedmodel)
    Analysis of Variance Table
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
    MVPAper  1 3895.9  3895.9 13.7296
    Age      3  231.0    77.0  0.2713

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  `car::Anova(mixedmodel)` will give you Wald tests of the individual terms in the model.

Long answer: there's probably not a significant effect of age in the model. Focusing on the summary for the age parameters only:

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value
Age9         0.0908241  0.7482005   0.121
Age12       -0.3519625  0.7478261  -0.471
Age15       -0.4881878  0.7499429  -0.651
```

These three t-values are quite small, i.e. <2. A value of 1.96 would be significant for a single term (the Normal approximation should be just fine since you have a large number of groups [1023]), slightly lower values might combine to be significant for the three terms (especially if they were strongly negatively correlated, which they're not), but I doubt that values of (0.121, -0.471, -0.651) will be jointly significant.

The effect of `MVApaper` is probably significant. `2*pnorm(3.615,lower.tail=FALSE)` gives a 2-tailed p-value of 0.0003. People worry a lot about t-distribution degrees of freedom, but with 1023 groups that won't matter at all.

- If more than a few children are measured at multiple ages, you might want to consider a random-slopes model `(Age|child_ID)`.
- It might be useful (although it won't change your overall fit/level of significance) to use successive-differences contrasts (`MASS::contr.sdif()`), i.e. `library(MASS); lmer(...,contrasts=list(Age="contr.sdif"))`.

Comment: @Michael L., why did you delete your answer? It does overlap a lot with mine, but it has some non-redundant useful stuff in it as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm assuming that ill remove the random effect of 1|Child ID with the Age|Child ID?

Comment: Is there a way to produce a graph of the model with four different lines (one for each age)

Comment: see `?predict.merMod`: set up a `newdata` data frame with `expand.grid(MVApaper=seq(min(MVApaper),max(MVApaper),n=51), Age=levels(Age))`, then plot the results